# Changing a span display into a readonly input

Tags: javascript

I have a timer countdown which displays in a `<span>`, I need it to output into a readonly `<input>` instead so I can calculate with the value. Is there any way to change this?

I tried

```
document.getElementById("timedown").value = display;
```

I tried various other things which just got messy and didn't work. Below is the function and the input

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var start = Date.now(),
    diff,
    minutes,
    seconds;
function timer() {
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

    if (diff <= 0) {
        // faaopoopo se tasi sekone

        start = Date.now() + 1000;
    }
};
// amata vave
timer();
setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {  
var fiveMinutes = 60 * 10,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');

startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<div class="transtime">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="timedown" value="0" readonly/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Too little code to answer. Where is the code that sets the span content? Also "messy" is not a very good description

Comment: What exactly can you not do with the `span`?

Comment: If you want to change span to input, just for giving the value of input, use `text` of span instead.

Comment: @mplungjan I have added the rest of the code... messy was a pretty good description unfortunately since I had to restore from backup a couple of times, I know very little about js

Comment: @MehdiDehghani how would I do that?

Comment: `var mySpan = document.getElementById('ID'); var value = mySpan.innerHTML;`

Comment: thanks thats new to me, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("timedown").value = minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

or change

```
display = document.querySelector('#timedown');
```

and

```
display.value = minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a working codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/zvYLMY)
Change the function to this:

```
    function timer() {
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
   seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.value= minutes + ":" + seconds; 

    if (diff <= 0) {
        // faaopoopo se tasi sekone

        start = Date.now() + 1000;
    }
};
```

changing the value instead of the text value and it should work

Comment: excellent, I'll upvote later I've run out of votes today, thanks

Comment: This requires the ID of the input to be `time` or to change to `display = document.querySelector('#timedown');` as I suggested